# How do I denote the set of all the elements of a cyclic group?

Tags: group-theory, notation

For example, can I simply write $\langle a\rangle$? (from Wikipedia)

And furthermore, is there some notation involving the representative symbol/name of the group, like $\underline{G}$ or $Elements(G)$, for instance?

Comment: If the group is called $G$ then $G$ also refers to the set of all the elements in the group.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Now that simplifies things^^

Comment: yes, you can  write $\langle a\rangle$ for the group generated by $a$, elements of the group are then simply $a^k,k\geq0$

Comment: @user190080 Many people call $\mathbb Z$ a cyclic group, so even if you were only talking about cyclic groups, and not groups in general, you'd have trouble with that $k\geq 0$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews point taken, it wouldn't be really convenient to do that...so let's say $k\in \mathbb Z$ then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to Tobias' comment, you *can* make a distinction between a group $G = (S, \cdot, 1)$, i.e., a structure, and the set $S$ of its elements.